# Entity Framework load and local to get ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, observablecollection

I can't get updated result and show it into datagrid, here is my code :

Xaml :

```
<Button Content="Button"
        Click="Button_Click"
        Margin="0,90,0,116" />
<DataGrid x:Name="manPowerOrgDataGrid"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}"
          Margin="0,0,0,184">
</DataGrid>
```

in Code Behind I use Load method and Local property to get an ObservableCollection :

```
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        using (DesignerEntities db=new DesignerEntities())
        {
            db.ManPowerOrgs.Load();
            DataContext = db.ManPowerOrgs.Local;
        } 
    }
```

Save Changes and Refresh :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (DesignerEntities db=new DesignerEntities())
    {
        db.ManPowerOrgs.Add(new ManPowerOrg() { Caption = "A", Number = 1, SMonth = 100 });
        db.SaveChanges();
        manPowerOrgDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
    }
}
```

But the updated result won't show on my UI!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest not binding directly to a DbSet. Using an ObservableCollection might be more appropriate.

For example:

```
public ObservableCollection<ManPowerOrg> MyList = new ObservableCollection<ManPowerOrg>();
  public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        using (DesignerEntities db = new DesignerEntities())
        {
            foreach (var item in db.ManPowerOrgs.ToList())
            {
                MyList.Add(item);
            }
        }
       DataContext = this;
    }


 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (DesignerEntities db = new DesignerEntities())
        {
            ManPowerOrg myItem = new ManPowerOrg() {Caption = "A", Number = 1, SMonth = 100};
            db.ManPowerOrgs.Add(myItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
            MyList.Add(myItem);
        }
    }
```

And then don't forget to change the binding:

```
  <DataGrid x:Name="manPowerOrgDataGrid"
      ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
      Margin="0,0,0,184">
```

Comment: I'm not binding to database, entity framework has a "local" property which gives me an observablecollection. I figure out how to adding and removing and show the changed result in datagrid, but I'm not satisfy with updating, because I have to invoke refresh method on datagrid items. and because I use MVVM, I don't how to refresh datagrid items without a x:name!!!...

Comment: Can you try the code I posted, it will probably update without the call to Refresh()

Comment: @Kourosh so, Is using datagridName.Items.Refresh() works but not satisfy you because it violates MVVM? Or Is it not working at all (can't make UI updated) as said in the question?

Comment: I try it and it worked, thanks for that... I'm telling you, it works with adding and removing, but not for updating :(

Comment: @har07 no man, I was questioning how to to refresh on datagrid items in viewmodel!! cause I don't have any access to datagrid!! it just binding!

Comment: Ok, by 'updating' I presume you mean when you already have an item in the observablecollection and also in the DB and then you assign new attribute values to that object. The object in the db gets updated but since you are not adding or removing anything to the observablecollection, the collectionchanged event isn't firing. What you need to do is implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface for the ManPowerOrg class. Simple way to do it is to go to Nuget, get the Fody.ProperyChanged package and add [ImplementPropertyChanged] tag to the ManPowerOrg class.